# Custom view for leftBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, uikit

Why when i adding custom view to leftBarButtonItem and click to leftBarButtonItem the menu doest appear?

```
let leftBarView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        leftBarView.backgroundColor = .red
        leftBarView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: leftBarView)

barButtonItem.menu = menu

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Comment: Can you show the full code. How is menu initialised?